# How do I check my MySQL connection in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a project that involves accessing the MySQL database. I know how to make a connection to the database using `mysqli`, but I don't know how to check the connection.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_connect_error($link)` or `$link->connect_error`.

```
if ($link->connect_error) {
  die("MySQL connection error: ".$link->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: is that not `connect_error` rather than `connection_error`?

Comment: You're right RamRaider, you need to use `connect_error`.

Comment: I've edited it to show the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @daCoder848 it's a very bad practice. Your site's users are not interesting in seeing mysql connection errors. It makes your site looks unprofessional and may leak sensitive information to a malicious user

Comment: Maybe, you could use `header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error"); die();`.

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)